# How to access vue-mc model key?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to implement models and collections in Vue.js, everything is working except that I can't access the models key e.g `item.name` from child.

Before models and collections I made straight api call with axios and then got objects like this:

```
[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
```

But with collections they are like this:

```
[ClientModel, ClientModel, ClientModel, ClientModel, ClientModel, __ob__: Observer]
```

This is how I am doing it inside the parent:

```
mounted() {
  this.clients.fetch().then(response => {
    console.log('Fetched clients', this.clients.models[0].name);//it works but only in the component itself.
    this.users_list = this.clients.models
  })
}

data() {
  let clients_collection = new AccountClientCollection()
  let client = new ClientModel({}, clients_collection)
  return {
    users_list: []
  }
}
```

So the question is, how to access vue-mc model key? And [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/n975nxl42p) is the sandbox I made. The issue is lying under the Test.vue file in `computed` `filtered_items` function.

Comment: What exactly isn't working as expected? Can you show the lines of code that are giving you unexpected results? You say you can't access `item.name`, but how is `item` being set?

Comment: @thanksd [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/n975nxl42p) is the sandbox I made. The issue is lying under the Test.vue file in `computed` `filtered_items`